# Concatenate string parameters with Python

Tags: python, string, function, tuples

Am trying to implement a concatenation of strings in python, these strings are passed into the function as multiple parameters via a tuple...I just quite can't figure out how to process multiple string parameters and use `join` method to put a `-` delimiter between the strings. For example when i pass values `I`, `Love`,`Python`, am expecting to see `I-Love-Python`..
Check out below

```
##Define a function that takes multiple string arguments
def concatenate(*args):
         #Got a problem processing the tuple elements and append delimiter - to the end of each word
         #Tried using a set with its add method but it didn't work
          u=len(args)#Get the length of the arguments tuple
          myarray={0}#initialize a new set to length 0
          for k in range(0, u):
            myarray.add(args[k]+"-")#append delimiter for every tuple member
             return myarray
        
##call concatenate with parameters and print
print(concatenate("I","Love","Python"))
```

Comment: The key with `join` is that it's a method on the delimiter, which in this case is `'-'`.  Hence: `return '-'.join(args)`

Comment: Are you aware that this directly works as ``"-".join(("I","Love","Python"))``?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to properly format the code. Right now, it cannot even run due to a SyntaxError.

Comment: Sorry for that, editing

Comment: @Samwise, Thanks so much, your comment worked without a hich :))

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Yes but i need a function call

Answer (score 1):

**Change your code as shown below:**

```
##Define a function that takes multiple string arguments
def concatenate(*args):
    return "-".join(args)
        
##call concatenate with parameters and print
print(concatenate("I","Love","Python"))
```

**OUTPUT:**

'I-Love-Python'

Comment: Hey, this was answered in a comment

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comments section above, you can simply use Python's built-in string function, i.e., `.join()`, to concatenate multiple string parameters separated by a delimiter (in this case, that is `-`). Example:

```py
s = '-'.join(['I','Love','Python'])
print(s)
# I-Love-Python
```

**Note**: if you have non-string attributes, you have to convert those to strings first. For example:

```
points = 3
s = '-'.join(['Each','player', 'has', str(points),'points'])
print(s)
# Each-player-has-3-points
```

If you need to do this in a function that expects a number of arguments (i.e., `*args`), then simply `return '-'.join(args)`. Again, remember to convert any non-string arguments first.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything over the existing answer, does it? Dealing with non-string arguments seems superfluous when the question explicitly doesn't need that case.